# Python requests.post throwing decryption failed or bad record mac when working with larger size files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ngrok, openai-whisper

I'm making a POST request from one of my python applications as below :

```py
with open(file_name, "rb") as audio_file:
    ngrok_url = 'https://****-***-***-*-**.ngrok-free.app/transcribe'
    response = requests.post(ngrok_url, data = audio_file, stream=True)
    transcription = json.loads(response.text)
```

and in a separate flask application, which is running on a ngrok agent to give me a public address, I'm fetching and feeding the audio to whisper for doing transcription as below :

```py
@app.route('/transcribe', methods=["POST"])
def transribe_audio():
    with open('test_audio.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in request.stream:
            f.write(chunk)
    model = whisper.load_model("base")
    result = model.transcribe('test_audio.mp3', word_timestamps=True)
    response = json.dumps(result)
    return response
```

While this is working perfectly fine with audio files <1MB, I get below error in my requests.post script for any large file sizes(So far tested with 25mb and bigger files) :

**Updating with complete error log for better understanding**

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****-***-***-*-**.ngrok-free.app',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /transcribe (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0e45-175-101-4-11.ngrok-free.app', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /transcribe (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] 
decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trsncrpt/myservice.py", line 162, in processWhisperOpenai
    response = requests.post(ngrok_url, data = audio_file, stream=True)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_dev/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****-***-***-*-**.ngrok-free.app', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /transcribe (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] 
decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)')))
```

I'm running whisper on cpu : `AMD Ryzen 5 2500U`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specifics of your case, but I had encountered a similar error in a flask application while using a different library. The issue in my case happened because gunicorn would try to multithread openssl (I think), and went away when I either

1. set threads = 1 in gunicorn
2. Used a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) on the function that makes the request
3. Created a processpool to make the request in another process.

It even caused some interpreter crashes in my case when there were ~10-20 concurrent requests.

Comment: Hmmm.... Since it's only throwing this error when posting larger files, I wonder if it's because the openai whisper model is taking very long time to transcribe the audio and send back the response to the first script. I might be wrong though and the issue could be with something else altogether.